# Chain value of string variable with some text and print it to standard output in C++

Tags: c++, string, stdout, bit-shift

I want to do something really simple: I have function that has string parameter and I want to chain it to some constant string, then output result to console like this:

```
void test(string s){
    cout << "Parameter of this function was: " << s;
}
```

In other languages chaining like this works, but in C++ the compiler is unhappy: `error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably forgot to `#include <string>` or `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio are you using? Your code sample is correct C++ (as long as you have the appropriate "using namespace std;").

Putting similar code through g++ works fine.